Is there a configuration file for the xPack OpenOCD for the PUYA PY32F003F18U6TR Microcontroller?
I am trying to use the PY32F003F18U6TR in a project and I do not want to use the Keil uVision IDE from ARM, but want to use VS Code with GNU ARM Toolchain and xPack OpenOCD. I have tried it with STM Microcontrollers (the Blue Pill) and it has worked, but now I am trying to initialize the PY32 Microcontroller and just get an LED blinking for starters.
I have downloaded the CMSIS Device Family Package from ARM and found the startup file for the gcc Assembler and I also found a HAL Library for the Peripherals and another for Low Level Programming, and I think that all is initialized correctly and the Assembler compiled the program correctly without any errors and I have a file (app.elf)!
But when I tried to flash and debug the program, the OpenOCD server kept closing and eventually I have copied the configuration file for the stm32F0 family and just changed the  set _CPUTAPID from 0x0bb11477 to 0x0bc11477, now the server starts but what I understood is that the microcontrollers keeps crashing.
these are the errors when I try to start the OpenOCD server:
1- A pop up appear from VS Code:
Failed to launch GDB: Remote communication error. Target disconnected.: (undocummented error 10061). (from target-select extended-remote localhost:50000)
2- on the terminal (gdb-server):
Waiting for gdb server to start...[2024-09-27T07:07:03.761Z] SERVER CONSOLE DEBUG: onBackendConnect: gdb-server session connected. You can switch to "DEBUG CONSOLE" to see GDB interactions.
"D:/Programs/openocd/bin/openocd" -c "gdb_port 50000" -c "tcl_port 50001" -c "telnet_port 50002" -s "C:\\............." -f "c:/Users/...../.vscode/extensions/marus25.cortex-debug-1.12.1/support/openocd-helpers.tcl" -f "D:/Programs/openocd/openocd/scripts/interface/stlink.cfg" -f "D:/Programs/openocd/openocd/scripts/target/py32f0xx.cfg"
xPack Open On-Chip Debugger 0.12.0+dev-01685-gb9224c0c0-dirty (2024-08-02-19:51)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
        http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
DEPRECATED! use 'gdb port', not 'gdb_port'
DEPRECATED! use 'tcl port' not 'tcl_port'
CDLiveWatchSetup
Info : auto-selecting first available session transport "hla_swd". To override use 'transport select <transport>'.
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
Info : Listening on port 50001 for tcl connections
Info : Listening on port 50002 for telnet connections
Info : clock speed 1000 kHz
Info : STLINK V2J42S7 (API v2) VID:PID 0483:3748
Info : Target voltage: 3.289186
Info : [stm32f0x.cpu] Cortex-M0+ r0p1 processor detected
Info : [stm32f0x.cpu] target has 4 breakpoints, 2 watchpoints
Info : [stm32f0x.cpu] Examination succeed
Info : [stm32f0x.cpu] starting gdb server on 50000
Info : Listening on port 50000 for gdb connections
Info : accepting 'gdb' connection on tcp/50000
[stm32f0x.cpu] halted due to debug-request, current mode: Handler HardFault
xPSR: 0x91000003 pc: 0xfffffffe msp: 0xffffffd8
Info : device id = 0x60001000
Warn : Cannot identify target as a STM32 family.
Error: auto_probe failed
Error: Connect failed. Consider setting up a gdb-attach event for the target to prepare target for GDB connect, or use 'gdb_memory_map disable'.
Error: attempted 'gdb' connection rejected
[2024-09-27T07:07:06.440Z] SERVER CONSOLE DEBUG: onBackendConnect: gdb-server session closed
GDB server session ended. This terminal will be reused, waiting for next session to start...

3- Debug Console:
"configuration": {
    "name": "Cortex Debug",
    "cwd": "C:\\Users\\..........................",
    "executable": "C:/Users/............./build/app.elf",
    "request": "launch",
    "type": "cortex-debug",
    "runToEntryPoint": "main",
    "servertype": "openocd",
    "device": "PY32F003X8",
    "interface": "swd",
    "svdFile": "C:\\Users\\............../lib/CMSIS/SVD/py32f003xx.svd",
    "configFiles": [
        "D:/Programs/openocd/openocd/scripts/interface/stlink.cfg",
        "D:/Programs/openocd/openocd/scripts/target/py32f0xx.cfg"
    ],
    "showDevDebugOutput": "parsed",
    "swoConfig": {
        "enabled": true,
        "cpuFrequency": 8000000,
        "swoFrequency": 4000000,
        "source": "probe",
        "decoders": [
            {
                "label": "ITM port 0 output",
                "type": "console",
                "port": 0,
                "showOnStartup": true,
                "encoding": "ascii"
            }
        ]
    },
    "runToMain": true,
    "__configurationTarget": 6,
    "gdbServerConsolePort": 60000,
    "pvtAvoidPorts": [],
    "chainedConfigurations": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "debuggerArgs": [],
    "rttConfig": {
        "enabled": false,
        "decoders": []
    },
    "graphConfig": [],
    "preLaunchCommands": [],
    "postLaunchCommands": [],
    "preAttachCommands": [],
    "postAttachCommands": [],
    "preRestartCommands": [],
    "postRestartCommands": [],
    "preResetCommands": [],
    "postResetCommands": [],
    "serverpath": "D:/Programs/openocd/bin/openocd",
   "searchDir": [],
    "toolchainPrefix": "arm-none-eabi",
    "gdbPath": "D:/Programs/gcc-arm-none-eabi/bin/arm-none-eabi-gdb",
    "extensionPath": "c:/Users/...................",
    "registerUseNaturalFormat": true,
    "variableUseNaturalFormat": true,
    "pvtVersion": "1.12.1",
    "__sessionId": "c7b0e550-1ac5-479b-9240-ef6e04976ac2",
    "pvtShowDevDebugOutput": "parsed"
}
Reading symbols from d:/programs/gcc-arm-none-eabi/bin/arm-none-eabi-objdump --syms -C -h -w C:/Users/.............../build/app.elf
Reading symbols from d:/programs/gcc-arm-none-eabi/bin/arm-none-eabi-nm --defined-only -S -l -C -p C:/Users/................../build/app.elf
Launching GDB: "D:/Programs/gcc-arm-none-eabi/bin/arm-none-eabi-gdb" -q --interpreter=mi2
1-gdb-version
Launching gdb-server: "D:/Programs/openocd/bin/openocd" -c "gdb_port 50000" -c "tcl_port 50001" -c "telnet_port 50002" -s "C:\\Users\\................." -f "c:/Users/......./.vscode/extensions/marus25.cortex-debug-1.12.1/support/openocd-helpers.tcl" -f "D:/Programs/openocd/openocd/scripts/interface/stlink.cfg" -f "D:/Programs/openocd/openocd/scripts/target/py32f0xx.cfg"
    Please check TERMINAL tab (gdb-server) for output from D:/Programs/openocd/bin/openocd
Finished reading symbols from objdump: Time: 586 ms
Finished reading symbols from nm: Time: 478 ms
D:\Programs\gcc-arm-none-eabi\bin\arm-none-eabi-gdb.exe: warning: Couldn't determine a path for the index cache directory.
GDB -> App: {"output":"","outOfBandRecord":[{"isStream":false,"type":"notify","asyncClass":"thread-group-added","output":[["id","i1"]]}]}
GDB -> App: {"output":"","outOfBandRecord":[{"isStream":true,"type":"console","content":"GNU gdb (GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain 10.3-2021.10) 10.2.90.20210621-git\n"}]}
GDB -> App: {"output":"","outOfBandRecord":[{"isStream":true,"type":"console","content":"Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.\n"}]}
GDB -> App: {"output":"","outOfBandRecord":[{"isStream":true,"type":"console","content":"License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>\nThis is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.\nThere is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law."}]}
GDB -> App: {"output":"","outOfBandRecord":[{"isStream":true,"type":"console","content":"\nType \"show copying\" and \"show warranty\" for details.\n"}]}
GDB -> App: {"output":"","outOfBandRecord":[{"isStream":true,"type":"console","content":"This GDB was configured as \"--host=i686-w64-mingw32 --target=arm-none-eabi\".\n"}]}
GDB -> App: {"output":"","outOfBandRecord":[{"isStream":true,"type":"console","content":"Type \"show configuration\" for configuration details.\n"}]}
GDB -> App: {"output":"","outOfBandRecord":[{"isStream":true,"type":"console","content":"For bug reporting instructions, please see:\n"}]}
GDB -> App: {"output":"","outOfBandRecord":[{"isStream":true,"type":"console","content":"<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.\n"}]}
GDB -> App: {"output":"","outOfBandRecord":[{"isStream":true,"type":"console","content":"Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:\n    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>."}]}
GDB -> App: {"output":"","outOfBandRecord":[{"isStream":true,"type":"console","content":"\n\n"}]}
GDB -> App: {"output":"","outOfBandRecord":[{"isStream":true,"type":"console","content":"For help, type \"help\".\n"}]}
GDB -> App: {"output":"","outOfBandRecord":[{"isStream":true,"type":"console","content":"Type \"apropos word\" to search for commands related to \"word\".\n"}]}
GDB -> App: {"output":"","token":1,"outOfBandRecord":[],"resultRecords":{"resultClass":"done","results":[]}}
2-gdb-set mi-async on
GDB -> App: {"output":"","token":2,"outOfBandRecord":[],"resultRecords":{"resultClass":"done","results":[]}}
3-interpreter-exec console "set print demangle on"
GDB -> App: {"output":"","token":3,"outOfBandRecord":[],"resultRecords":{"resultClass":"done","results":[]}}
4-interpreter-exec console "set print asm-demangle on"
GDB -> App: {"output":"","outOfBandRecord":[{"isStream":false,"type":"notify","asyncClass":"cmd-param-changed","output":[["param","print asm-demangle"],["value","on"]]}]}
GDB -> App: {"output":"","token":4,"outOfBandRecord":[],"resultRecords":{"resultClass":"done","results":[]}}
5-enable-pretty-printing
GDB -> App: {"output":"","token":5,"outOfBandRecord":[],"resultRecords":{"resultClass":"done","results":[]}}
6-interpreter-exec console "source c:/Users/omarr/.vscode/extensions/marus25.cortex-debug-1.12.1/support/gdbsupport.init"
GDB -> App: {"output":"","token":6,"outOfBandRecord":[],"resultRecords":{"resultClass":"done","results":[]}}
7-interpreter-exec console "source c:/Users/omarr/.vscode/extensions/marus25.cortex-debug-1.12.1/support/gdb-swo.init"
GDB -> App: {"output":"","outOfBandRecord":[{"isStream":false,"type":"notify","asyncClass":"cmd-param-changed","output":[["param","language"],["value","c"]]}]}
GDB -> App: {"output":"","outOfBandRecord":[{"isStream":false,"type":"notify","asyncClass":"cmd-param-changed","output":[["param","language"],["value","auto"]]}]}
GDB -> App: {"output":"","token":7,"outOfBandRecord":[],"resultRecords":{"resultClass":"done","results":[]}}
8-interpreter-exec console "set output-radix 0xa"
GDB -> App: {"output":"","outOfBandRecord":[{"isStream":true,"type":"console","content":"Output radix now set to decimal 10, hex a, octal 12.\n"}]}
Output radix now set to decimal 10, hex a, octal 12.
GDB -> App: {"output":"","token":8,"outOfBandRecord":[],"resultRecords":{"resultClass":"done","results":[]}}
9-interpreter-exec console "set input-radix 0xa"
GDB -> App: {"output":"","outOfBandRecord":[{"isStream":true,"type":"console","content":"Input radix now set to decimal 10, hex a, octal 12.\n"}]}
Input radix now set to decimal 10, hex a, octal 12.
GDB -> App: {"output":"","token":9,"outOfBandRecord":[],"resultRecords":{"resultClass":"done","results":[]}}
10-file-exec-and-symbols "C:/Users/.............../build/app.elf"
GDB -> App: {"output":"","token":10,"outOfBandRecord":[],"resultRecords":{"resultClass":"done","results":[]}}
11-target-select extended-remote localhost:50000
GDB -> App: {"output":"","token":11,"outOfBandRecord":[],"resultRecords":{"resultClass":"error","results":[["msg","Remote communication error.  Target disconnected.: (undocumented errno 10061)."]]}}
12-interpreter-exec console "monitor reset halt"
Failed to launch GDB: Remote communication error.  Target disconnected.: (undocumented errno 10061). (from target-select extended-remote localhost:50000)

If anybody have tried this way, even if not Puya Microcontroller, I hope to know how you managed to make a configuration file for the openocd for the target.
thanks in advance
